# What is meant by “how an element in the domain is mapped to its image”.

Tags: soft-question, notation, multilinear-algebra

In the following [lecture](https://youtu.be/mbv3T15nWq0) given by Fredric Schuller, he mentions this  during the lecture which is on multilinear algebra (know that $P$ is a set of polynomials such that $p$ $\in$ $P$):

“consider the map $I$: $P$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$, **now I need to say how a polynomial is mapped to a real number**

$I(p)$ $:= $$\int_0^1$$p(x)dx$“

My questions is: What does he mean when he says “how a polynomial is mapped to a real number”? Is he simply referring to the definition of $I$? I’ve just never heard someone say that instead of saying “The map $I$ is defined as...”

Comment: I think you are correct in your interpretation and your critique.  I suspect that somehow in the lecture it came up that we *needed* a map and had to consider what a map could possibly be and he is merely emphasing that we must somehow define it and that actual definition is significant.  But I think you are right.  I think he is just saying "Let's defin $I:R\to \mathbb R$ by ...."

Comment: " I’ve just never heard someone say that instead of saying “The map I is defined as...” "  I haven't heard this precisely, but I have heard lectures where we need a map from two spaces with specific properties and there is a bit of an excercise that we define the function in just the right way to get our result.  The psychology of the language is just to empasize we didn't just trip over the function in a junkyard; that we actually had to consciously construct it.  .... In terms of *math*... there's not difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is just defining the mapping. He is saying: I am defining a mapping $I: P \to \mathbb{R}$ which assigns to each polynomial $p(x)$ the real number $\int_0^1 p(x) dx$.

Comment: So, in that light, the definition of a function such as $I$ (or any relation) describes how an element in the domain is assigned to its image?

Comment: @MathDoctorR Yes, a specific  function is not properly defined until you explain how it is applied to elements in the domain.